# Вопрос по сравнению строк без учета регистра

Tags: python

Когда начинал учить python, это было пару месяцев назад, тогда я ответ смог нагуглить,а щас нет((
В общем сам вопрос:

```
s = input("Как дела?")
if s =='Хорошо':
print ("Отлично!")
```

В данной схеме показано что если ответят "Хорошо", то ответ будет 'Отлично!'
Но, если написать 'хорошо', будет ошибка, потому что не учтен регистр, по этому мне нужно чтобы была переменная со всеми нужными словами, т.е допустим `d ='хорошо,'Хорошо,'ХАРАШО','Нормально','нормально', 'Отлично!','отлично,'Атлична!'.`
Вот! Я хочу чтобы если пользователь ответит одним словом из слов переменной d, уже выдавало ответ. А не только когда он пишет именно 'Отлично'.
Я знаю это сложно было объяснить,мало кто поймет, но помогите плииз, голову уже сломал)))

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
s = input("Как дела?")
d = ['хорошо', 'Хорошо', 'ХАРАШО', 'Нормально',
     'нормально', 'Отлично!','отлично', 'Атлична!']
if s in d:
    print("Отлично!")
```

А для приведения строк к одному регистру, обратите внимание на пример:

```
s = 'оТлИчНо'
d = ['хорошо', 'Отлично', 'Атлична!']
if s.casefold() in map(str.casefold, d):
    print("Отлично!")
```

Использование `str.lower()` - плохая идея. У некоторых символов получаем:

```
str.upper().lower() == str.lower()  # False
```

Comment: Спасибо! Черт подери я забыл про in, мой код выглядел так
while True:
    voprosi = 'Как дела','как дела','Как дела?','как дела?'
    otveti = 'Хорошо!'
    s = input ("Введи вопрос: ")
    if s == voprosi:
        print (otveti)
    else:
        print ('Я тебя не понимаю')

Comment: можно просто приводить строку к одному регистру, например:
`if s.lower() == 'хорошо': ...`

Answer (score 1):

Думаю,что самым правильным будет чисто символьная проверка без учета регистра. То есть не включаем в список слова "хорошо" и "Хорошо", а только что-то одно. Например:

```
    s = input('Как дела?')
    answers = ['хорошо','харашо','отлично','атлична']
    if s.lower() in answers:
        print('Отлично')
```

Comment: Аккуратнее с переводом регистра. Выполни это: `'ß'.upper().lower() == 'ß'.lower()` и удивись. Используй: `s.casefold()`

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Нет никакого смысла делать операцию, которая никогда нигде не используется(upper.lower) и потом на основании этого говорить, что не нужно использовать lower(). Заглавная ß, кстати, уже существует два года, но ещё не до всех шрифтов и языков дошла.

Comment: @Эникейщик Это хрестоматийный пример того, что бывает, если менять регистр символов, которые существуют только в одном регистре. Посмотри результат: `'ß'.upper()`. Не везде есть только русские и английские символы, юникод - большой. `casefold` - инструмент, специально предназначенный для данной задачи.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov если честно, то в случае с 'ß'.casefold() тоже не получается ничего хорошего, а именно: 'ss'.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вот обсуждения этой проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison/29247821#29247821 повторять опыт подобных обсуждений, я сейчас не хочу.